# Wrap full stop in span tag using pure JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple string and if the last character of that string is a full stop, I want to wrap it with `span` tags so that I can change its colour. However, my logic doesn't seem to be working?

```js
var title = document.querySelector(".textHero__title");
title = title.textContent.trim();
const fullstop = ".";

if( title.endsWith(fullstop) ){
  console.log("true");
  title.replace(fullstop, '<span>.</span>');
}
```

```css
html{
  background: black
}

.textHero__title{
  color: red;
}

.textHero__title span{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="textHero__title">
  This is a title.
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace` returns a new string. Strings in js are immutable.

Also, you have to call some DOM API to update the DOM.

`innerHTML` will be enough in this scenario

```js
var title = document.querySelector(".textHero__title");
const titleText = title.textContent.trim();
const fullstop = ".";

if (titleText.endsWith(fullstop)) {
  console.log("true");
  const replaced = titleText.replace(fullstop, '<span>.</span>');
  title.innerHTML = replaced
}
```

```css
html {
  background: black
}

.textHero__title {
  color: red;
}

.textHero__title span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="textHero__title">
  This is a title.
</h1>
```

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said in the comment:

> Another problem: replace() replaces the first match, but he wants to replace the . at the end.

In this case it doesn't matter, because you have one full stop, but if you had more, you would have to use regex with a global flag

```js
var title = document.querySelector(".textHero__title");
const titleText = title.textContent.trim();
const fullstop = /\./g;

if (titleText.match(fullstop)) {
  console.log("true");
  const replaced = titleText.replace(fullstop, '<span>.</span>');
  title.innerHTML = replaced
}
```

```css
html {
  background: black
}

.textHero__title {
  color: red;
}

.textHero__title span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="textHero__title">
  This is a title. And this is a subtitle.
</h1>
```

Comment: Another problem: `replace()` replaces the first match, but he wants to replace the `.` at the end.

Comment: Thanks both for the answer / input. The solution works perfectly :)